# PTC Integrity to get the latest code from repository

Tags: checkout, integrity, mks

how to get the latest version of code from the MKS repository ??

using MKS commands

Comment: do you want command line options or from Gui

Answer (score 2):

To get last version of a project from mks repository, first you should create a sandbox and then you can resync the sandbox with server.

To create a sandbox use the command `si createsandbox`
    si createsandbox --project=%mks_Project% -R -Y %sandboxLocation%
this command will create a sandbox of project from normal line. If you work on devpath then you should add `--devpath=%projectDevpath%` on the command

To resync a sandbox use the command `si resync --sandbox=%sandboxName%`. e.g. `si resync --sandbox="D:/sandbox/project1/project.pj"`

Please be sure you replace all fields between `%` this the proper value. Depending of your server configuration, the command cand be diferent.

**sI createsanbox help**

```
    Usage: si createsandbox options... directory; options are:
        --lineTerminator=[lf|crlf|native|cr]  Line terminator to use in this sandbox
        --[no]populate  Populate sandbox with members
        -R  Recurse into subsandboxes creation
        --[no|confirm]recurse  Recurse into subsandboxes creation
        --scope=attribute:name[=value]
                 memberrevlabellike:<expression>
                 anyrevlabellike:<expression>
                 name:<expression>
                 path:<expression>
                 type:text|binary
                 any
        --[no]shared  Allow sandbox to be shared
        --[no]sparse  Create sparse sandbox
        --[no]openView  Activate sandbox view after completing the command
        --devpath=value  The development path (to refer variant projects)
        --[no]failOnAmbiguousProject  Whether to abort when multiple projects correspond to a flat project string.
        -P value  The name of the target project
        --project=value  The name of the target project
        --projectRevision=value  The project revision (to refer build projects)
        --[no]awaitServer  If server does not respond, keep trying
        -?  Shows the usage for a command
        --[no]batch  Control batch mode (no user interaction in batch mode)
        --cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory
        -F value  Read the selection from a specified file
        --forceConfirm=[yes|no]  Specify an answer to all confirmation questions
        -g  User interaction should happen via the GUI
        --gui  User interaction should happen via the GUI
        --hostname=value  Hostname of server
        -N  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
        --no  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
        --password=value  Credentials (e.g., password) to login with
        --port=value  TCP/IP port number of server
        --quiet  Control status display
        --selectionFile=value  Read the selection from a specified file
        --settingsUI=[gui|default]  Control UI for command options
        --status=[none|gui|default]  Control status display
        --usage  Shows the usage for a command
        --user=value  Username to login to server with
        -Y  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
        --yes  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
```

**si resync help**

```
    Usage: si resync options... current or former member/subproject...; options are:
        --[no]byCP  Operate in change package mode
        --[no]confirm  In change package mode, proceed without a question
        --[no]confirmPopulateSparse  Confirm populate of a sparse sandbox
        --[no|confirm]downgradeOnLockConflict  Whether to downgrade my existing exclusive lock to a non exclusive lock if an exclusive lock already exists on the member revision
        --[no]includeDropped  Include former members
        --[no|confirm]merge  Perform merges if required
        --mergeType=[confirm|cancel|automatic|manual]  Try to automatically perform the merge or launch the conflict resolution tool
        --onMergeConflict=[confirm|cancel|mark|launchtool|highlight|error]  What to do when conflicts occurred during the merge
        --[no|confirm]overwriteIfPending  Force overwrite of working files which correspond to pending revisions or pending members.
        --[no]populate  Populate the sandbox with working files
        --[no|un]expand  Whether keywords should be expanded in working files
        -f  Force overwrite of changed working files
        --[no|confirm]overwriteChanged  Force overwrite of changed working files
        --[no|confirm]overwriteDeferred  Force overwrite of working files with deferred operations pending
        --[no]overwriteUnchanged  Force overwrite of unchanged working files
        --[no|confirm]removeOutOfScope  Force removal of out of scope working files
        --[no]restoreTimestamp  Set the timestamp on the working file to the revision's timestamp
        --filter=attribute:name[=value]
                 changed[:working|:sync|:newer|:size|:missing|:newmem|:all]
                 file:<expression>
                 frozen
                 label[:name]
                 locked[:name]
                 locktype[:exclusive|:nonexclusive|:any]
                 state[:name]
                 format[:text|:binary]
                 workingbranch
                 anylabel[:name]
                 deferred[:add|:addfromarchive|:checkin|:drop|:import|:move|:rename|:updaterevision|:all]
                 unresolvedmerges
                 memberonbranch
                 pending[:add|:addfromarchive|:drop|:import|:movememberfrom|:movememberto|:renamefrom|:renameto|:update|:updaterevision|:all]
                 workinprogress
                 sparsecontents
                 rule[:defined|:invalid|:memberrevdiffers]
                 archiveshared
                 caseinsensitivefile:<expression>
                 outofscope
        -R  Select recursively
        --[no|confirm]recurse  Select recursively
        --[no]failOnAmbiguousProject  Whether to abort when multiple projects correspond to a flat project string.
        -S value  The name of the sandbox
        --sandbox=value  The name of the sandbox
        --[no]awaitServer  If server does not respond, keep trying
        -?  Shows the usage for a command
        --[no]batch  Control batch mode (no user interaction in batch mode)
        --cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory
        -F value  Read the selection from a specified file
        --forceConfirm=[yes|no]  Specify an answer to all confirmation questions
        -g  User interaction should happen via the GUI
        --gui  User interaction should happen via the GUI
        --hostname=value  Hostname of server
        -N  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
        --no  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
        --password=value  Credentials (e.g., password) to login with
        --port=value  TCP/IP port number of server
        --quiet  Control status display
        --selectionFile=value  Read the selection from a specified file
        --settingsUI=[gui|default]  Control UI for command options
        --status=[none|gui|default]  Control status display
        --usage  Shows the usage for a command
        --user=value  Username to login to server with
        -Y  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
        --yes  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way shall be to check-out the head revision with/out lock.